# Can't get canvas of threejs next to a div

Tags: javascript, three.js

im making a shoe customizer and im having trouble with placing my canvas (of threejs) next to my div (the shoe customizer), i made a post asking the same question, but it didn't get resolved, i did adapt a few things based on the answers, but now the canvas is on top of the div, instead of next to it. PLEASE help.

Main question is: how do i get my canvas-container next to the customizer-container

html

```
  <body>
    <img class="logo-image" src="/public/SWEAR-logo.png" alt="SWEAR logo">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="canvas-container"></div>
        <div class="customizer-container">
          <img id="close-window" src="/public/close.png" alt="close-window">
          <h1 id="name"></h1>
          <div class="color-palette-container">
                <p>Colors</p>
                <div id="color-palette-laces">
                    <div><div class="box red" style="background-color: red;"></div> Red </div>
                    <div><div class="box green" style="background-color: green;"></div> Green </div>
                    <div><div class="box blue" style="background-color: blue;"></div> Blue </div>
                    <div><div class="box yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></div> Yellow </div>
                    <div><div class="box purple" style="background-color: purple;"></div> Purple </div>
                    <div><div class="box pink" style="background-color: pink;"></div> Pink </div>
                </div>

                <div id="color-palette-sole">
                  <div><div class="box red" style="background-color: red;"></div> Red </div>
                  <div><div class="box green" style="background-color: green;"></div> Green </div>
                  <div><div class="box blue" style="background-color: blue;"></div> Blue </div>
                  <div><div class="box yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></div> Yellow </div>
                  <div><div class="box purple" style="background-color: purple;"></div> Purple </div>
                  <div><div class="box pink" style="background-color: pink;"></div> Pink </div>
              </div>
                  
                <div id="color-palette-sole-top">
                  <div><div class="box red" style="background-color: red;"></div> Red </div>
                  <div><div class="box green" style="background-color: green;"></div> Green </div>
                  <div><div class="box blue" style="background-color: blue;"></div> Blue </div>
                  <div><div class="box yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></div> Yellow </div>
                  <div><div class="box purple" style="background-color: purple;"></div> Purple </div>
                  <div><div class="box pink" style="background-color: pink;"></div> Pink </div>
                </div>

                <div id="color-palette-outside1">
                  <div><div class="box red" style="background-color: red;"></div> Red </div>
                  <div><div class="box green" style="background-color: green;"></div> Green </div>
                  <div><div class="box blue" style="background-color: blue;"></div> Blue </div>
                  <div><div class="box yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></div> Yellow </div>
                  <div><div class="box purple" style="background-color: purple;"></div> Purple </div>
                  <div><div class="box pink" style="background-color: pink;"></div> Pink </div>
                </div>

                <div id="color-palette-outside2">
                  <div><div class="box red" style="background-color: red;"></div> Red </div>
                  <div><div class="box green" style="background-color: green;"></div> Green </div>
                  <div><div class="box blue" style="background-color: blue;"></div> Blue </div>
                  <div><div class="box yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></div> Yellow </div>
                  <div><div class="box purple" style="background-color: purple;"></div> Purple </div>
                  <div><div class="box pink" style="background-color: pink;"></div> Pink </div>
                </div>

                <div id="color-palette-outside3">
                  <div><div class="box red" style="background-color: red;"></div> Red </div>
                  <div><div class="box green" style="background-color: green;"></div> Green </div>
                  <div><div class="box blue" style="background-color: blue;"></div> Blue </div>
                  <div><div class="box yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></div> Yellow </div>
                  <div><div class="box purple" style="background-color: purple;"></div> Purple </div>
                  <div><div class="box pink" style="background-color: pink;"></div> Pink </div>
                </div>

                <div id="color-palette-inside">
                  <div><div class="box red" style="background-color: red;"></div> Red </div>
                  <div><div class="box green" style="background-color: green;"></div> Green </div>
                  <div><div class="box blue" style="background-color: blue;"></div> Blue </div>
                  <div><div class="box yellow" style="background-color: yellow;"></div> Yellow </div>
                  <div><div class="box purple" style="background-color: purple;"></div> Purple </div>
                  <div><div class="box pink" style="background-color: pink;"></div> Pink </div>
                </div>


                  <p>Fabrics</p>
                  <div id="color-fabrics-laces">
                      <div><div class="box-fabric plastic" style="background-color: red;"></div> Plastic </div>
                      <div><div class="box-fabric metallic" style="background-image: url('/textures/metallic.jpg');"></div> Metallic </div>
                      <div><div class="box-fabric polyester" style="background-image: url('/textures/polyester.jpg');"></div> Polyester </div>
                      <div><div class="box-fabric leather" style="background-color: yellow;"></div> Leather </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="size-container">
              <label for="size">Size</label>
                <select name="size" id="size">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                  <option value="size-36">36</option>
                  <option value="size-37">37</option>
                  <option value="size-38">38</option>
                  <option value="size-39">39</option>
                  <option value="size-40">40</option>
                  <option value="size-41">41</option>
                  <option value="size-42">42</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              
            <button id="orderButton" disabled>Order now</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%
}

.customizer-container{
  width: 500px; 
  height:100vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.canvas-container {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

javascript

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas-container');
canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

what it looks like right now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ4nP.png)

so now they are stacked on top of eachother, but i want them side by side (canvas on the left, and customizer on the right), without the canvas being compressed

Link to full code: https://github.com/milanaismail/sneaker

Comment: Basically what do you mean *on top of the div*? Above or z-indexing, etc? Could you show sandbox or img of issue, for visualization what you want achieve?

Comment: i edited the post, there is a picture of what it looks like right now :)

Answer (score 0):

look at this

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .canvas-container, .customizer-container {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
    }

    .customizer-container {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
     }

    .canvas-container {
      flex: 1;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    .color-palette-container,
    .size-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .size-container {
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #orderButton {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="canvas-container"></div>
    <div class="customizer-container">
      <h1 id="name">Customizer</h1>
      <div class="color-palette-container">
        <p>Colors</p>
        <!-- Color palettes go here -->
      </div>
      <div class="color-palette-container">
        <p>Fabrics</p>
        <!-- Fabric options go here -->
      </div>
      <div class="size-container">
        <label for="size">Size</label>
        <select name="size" id="size">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
          <option value="size-36">36</option>
          <option value="size-37">37</option>
          <option value="size-38">38</option>
          <option value="size-39">39</option>
          <option value="size-40">40</option>
          <option value="size-41">41</option>
          <option value="size-42">42</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button id="orderButton" disabled>Order now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>

  <script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  const canvasContainer = document.querySelector('.canvas-container');
  canvasContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const icosahedronGeometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1, 0);
  const diamondMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00FFFF });
  const diamond = new THREE.Mesh(icosahedronGeometry, diamondMaterial);
  diamond.position.x = -3;
  scene.add(diamond);

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.enabled = true;

  const dL = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
  dL.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
  scene.add(dL);

  camera.position.z = 5;

  const rotationSpeed = 0.002;

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    diamond.rotation.x += rotationSpeed;
    diamond.rotation.y += rotationSpeed;
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  animate();

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const newWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const newHeight = window.innerHeight;
    camera.aspect = newWidth / newHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I dont understand what im doing wrong, but it is still stacked on top of eachother